# Make whole td clickable in rails, not just text - cant use js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Arrh, this is driving me nuts. In rails I have a table and I want the td's clickable. This works:
`<td><%= link_to 'Here', '#', remote: true %></td>`
The problem is that just the text is clickable and not the whole td. I cannot use jquery/js because I need the `remote: true` option to do an ajax request (unless somebody have another way for that). My css is this which has been recommended in other questions but no dice:
`td {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
td a {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}`
Is there maybe anything in Foundation or Bootstrap that can help?

Comment: Try to omit the `display` and use `min-width/height: 100%` within `td a` rule.

Comment: @Teemu, thanks but that makes the click-able area around the text even smaller

Comment: Remove height/width from td and any padding. Your styles for `td a` are correct. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/WyFL6/

Comment: Ok, your fiddle works, even if I add the height and width that I need to make td square. So I started digging, and the problem is foundation that adds padding to the td. So I explicitly set `padding: 0` and that works.